# How to Update Elastic Search Documents in bulk, using any other key apart "_id"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update the Elastic Search But my Key to match is different than "_id".

E.g:

```
{
"_op_type": "update",
"_index": "my_index",
"_type": "document",
"_id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
"doc": record,
"doc_as_upsert": True
}
```

Say My ES has 2 documents:

{ "1" : "Name1" }

{"2": "Name2"  }

// Keys are Unique here, But not uniformly distributed i.e why I have used uuid as "_id".

Question: I update to keep the last updated name corresponding to any key.

For: My name updates on time to time Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4 for same "1" Key, I want to keep just the last updated name in "1".

Comment: You question is not clear. What is the other field you want to use as key? Does that another field uniquely identify the documents. Please add [mcve]

Comment: Is there any reason to run this via bulk? Based on example given, looks like update will happen on individual basis, in which case, its better to use update by query.